# LINQ Query Result - dynamically get field value from a field name variable

Tags: linq, linq-to-objects

LINQ newbie here

I am trying to get a value of a field - using a fieldName variable. 
If I do a watch on row[FieldName] I do get a value - but when I do it on the actual code it will not compile.

```
string fieldName = "awx_name"

List<awx_property> propertyQry = 
            (
                from property in crm.awx_propertyawx_properties
                where property.awx_propertyid == new Guid(id)
                select property
            ).ToList();

            foreach (awx_property row in propertyQry)
            {
//THIS DOES NOT WORK
fieldValue = row[fieldName];   
}
```

Thanks in advance. Alternatives would be welcome as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You keep us guessing what you are trying to do here... You need to specify the types of the objects, so it's easy for us to understand and help. Anyway, I think you are trying to get an object based on the ID. Since you are getting by Id, my guess would be the return value is a single object.

```
var propertyObj =( from property in crm.awx_propertyawx_properties
                      where property.awx_propertyid == new Guid(id)
                      select property
                    ).SingleOrDefault();
   if(propertyObj != null) {
     fieldValue = propertyObj.GetType().GetProperty(fieldName).GetValue(propertyObj, null);
   }
```

Of course, you need to add validation to make sure you don't get null or any other error while accessing the property value.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

What type is fieldValue? What does awx_property look like? This will only work is awx_property is a key/value collection. It its not, you could use reflection instead.

If it is a key/value collection you are probably missing a cast. (row[FieldName].ToString() or something) Also you are missing a semi-colon in the foreach block.

Comment: If I do row.awx_name it works fine. Maybe I should check out that reflection deal...

Comment: Microsoft.Xrm.Client.CrmEntity.this[string]' is inaccessible due to its protection level ==> this is the compile error I get